# Apache MyFaces: VariableMapperWrapper.resolveVariable, StackOverflowError: Could not Resolve Variable [Overflow]

Tags: jsf-2, facelets

I wonder what's the reason for this exception having created new Facelets containing some includes. There is obviously a recursion inside the EL resolution. The debugging of the `VariableMapperWrapper.resolveVariable` method doesn't show anything special: EL resolution is happening ...

```
14.03.2013 17:20:13 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SCHWERWIEGEND: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:390)
        at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:119)
        at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.VariableMapperWrapper.resolveVariable(VariableMapperWrapper.java:96)
        at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.VariableMapperWrapper.resolveVariable(VariableMapperWrapper.java:89)
        at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.VariableMapperWrapper.resolveVariable(VariableMapperWrapper.java:89)
             ... (recursion) ...
        at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.VariableMapperWrapper.resolveVariable(VariableMapperWrapper.java:89)
        at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.VariableMapperWrapper.resolveVariable(VariableMapperWrapper.java:89)
        at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.VariableMapperWrapper.resolveVariable(VariableMapperWrapper.java:89)
        at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.VariableMapperWrapper.resolveVariable(VariableMapperWrapper.java:89)
        at com.sun.el.lang.VariableMapperFactory.resolveVariable(VariableMapperFactory.java:63)
        at com.sun.el.lang.ExpressionBuilder.visit(ExpressionBuilder.java:234)
        at com.sun.el.parser.SimpleNode.accept(SimpleNode.java:172)
        at com.sun.el.parser.SimpleNode.accept(SimpleNode.java:175)
        at com.sun.el.lang.ExpressionBuilder.prepare(ExpressionBuilder.java:186)
        at com.sun.el.lang.ExpressionBuilder.build(ExpressionBuilder.java:197)
        at com.sun.el.lang.ExpressionBuilder.createValueExpression(ExpressionBuilder.java:240)
        at com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl.createValueExpression(ExpressionFactoryImpl.java:98)
        at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.tag.TagAttributeImpl.getValueExpression(TagAttributeImpl.java:486)
        at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.tag.jsf.ValueHolderRule$DynamicValueExpressionMetadata.applyMetadata(ValueHolderRule.java:99)
        at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.tag.MetadataImpl.applyMetadata(MetadataImpl.java:45)
        at javax.faces.view.facelets.MetaTagHandler.setAttributes(MetaTagHandler.java:66)
        at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.setAttributes(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:93)
        at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegate.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegate.java:237)
        at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:53)
        at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:49)
        ...
```

Comment: Please post facelet code.

Answer (score 3):

It has finally emerged there was a special type of recursion inside the Facelets XHTML code. I noticed other people created such a recursion by inclusion of snippet chains like a.xhtml includes b.xhtml includes a.xhtml

In my case an included snippet contained a copy&paste error from the main XHTML page, the snippet header section:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<ui:composition template="xyz.xhtml">
...
```

--> `template="xyz.xhtml"` included the snippet above --> recursion.

**The removal of the anyway wrong template attribute resolved the problem.** In the end the exception above as the symptom of this problem was a bit far away from the error reason. The resolution was not at all obvious.